# using templates in php

Tags: php, templates

I'd like to write a website using php and templates.

I've seen some examples where the content of a template file is loaded via file_get_contents() and then all of the template placeholders are replaced with the actual values.

E.g.

```
$this->template = file_get_contents($this->templateFile);
```

And then:

```
public function assign($replace, $replacement) {
        $this->template = str_replace( $this->leftDelimiter .$replace.$this->rightDelimiter,
                                       $replacement, $this->template );
    }
```

Is this the correct and "state-of-the-art" way to do it? I have the feeling that it should somehow be more complicated :D I dont want to instigate a discussion, just some feedback on whether this is only used in tutorials or actually done this way.

Thanks for some feedback!

Comment: The best thing to do is use a template engine such as Twig, Smarty or Dwoo.

Comment: Templates field is too big, but yes, that's one way of doing it. Even pure is templating. And you can use something more fancy like smarty.

Comment: Use Smarty! You dont have to create the wheel again and again. There are better solutions out there

Comment: Based on experience I would advise strongly against Smarty.  It is such a pain working with loops.  Twig on the other hand I can recommend.  Many IDEs also support it.

Comment: PHP *is* a templating language of sorts. You can interleave PHP with any plaintext file that is parsed by PHP. Unless you go all out (like Smarty or Mustache), doing search/replace is just busy-work for the PHP engine; it is slower and does not give much value. In any case, there is no "correct" way of doing this. It depends on your needs/sensibilities.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the replies everyone!